# Making a button go to 2nd tabbed scene rather than 1st?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app with a tab controller that has 3 tabbed scenes.  The 1st is an intro with a static graphic and some text labels. The 2nd starts with a scrollable list of selectable apps, and contains multiple storyboards, each one which contains a separate app.  Each one of these ‘sub’ apps includes a button which – before I added a tab controller – would take the user back to the scrolling list in the current 2nd tab.  Ever since I added in the tab controller, the code below takes me back to the 1st (Intro) scene.  Is there any way of making the button go to the 2nd tab scene rather than the first?

```
- (void) goHome: (id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *Main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *mainScreen = [Main instantiateInitialViewController];
    mainScreen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:mainScreen animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Given your explanation in the comments, I think that the best approach to this would be using notifications. That is:

1. when the "goHome" button is pressed in one sub-app controller, a notification is posted;
2. the app list controller is registered to handle that kind of notifications, so it is notified when the button is pressed and can do what required.

This would look like this, more or less:

1. In your sub-app controller:

   ```
   - (void) goHome: (id)sender {

       NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
       [notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"GOHOMEPRESSED" object:nil userInfo:nil];

   }
   ```
2. In your app list controller:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {

      ...

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(goHome)
                                                name:@"GOHOMEPRESSED"
                                              object:nil];

      ...
   }

   - (void)goHome {

       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

   }
   ```

You can change the notification name used, of course (@"GOHOMEPRESSED") provided you use it consistently.

Don't forget to remove the observer in your app list controller's `dealloc` method (I leave this to you).

Also, try to get the logics behind this:

1. from a given controller you present a second controller (`presentViewController:Volumesapp`);
2. this will bring you altogether outside of the controller hierarchy where you were before (in your case, the tab bar);
3. when you are done with the presented controller, you must call `dismiss` on the presenting controller (the step done in 2/goHome), to get back (sort of) to where you were.

Hope this helps.

OLD ANSWER:

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, what you need is selecting the right sub-controller inside of your tab bar controller by using `setSelectedIndex`; something like this should work:

```
- (void) goHome: (id)sender
{
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
}
```

Your current solution will simply overlap your current controller with a new controller instance presented modally. So, you are not properly going to the first scene, to use your wording, your are altogether instantiating a new scene on top of the existing one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Did you mean to replace everything in my 'goHome' with your one line?  If so, it doesn't work. Pressing the UIButton for 'goHome' does nothing. Just stays on the same screen.

Comment: Check your `self.tabBarController` in `goHome` -- I assume it is nil. If it is, then there may be something you are not explaining about your app, since a view controller which is embedded in a tab bar controller has a non-nil `tabBarController`. Another possibility is that I am not understanding correctly how your app works and where the button that you tap is located... my understanding is that `goHome` belongs to one of the view controllers embedded in the tab bar controller...

Comment: sergio, thanks for your patience and contributions here. I have never used a Tab Bar Controller before, and I am (obviously!) struggling here.Let me try to explain a bit better. Before I tried to do anything with Tab Bar Controllers, I had an app that had an initial screen showing a scrolling list of 20 'sub' apps, each with their own storyboard, .h and .m files. Each app was selectable from the first screen, and also each one had a button that ran 'goHome' (as originally posted). When that button was tapped, the user was taken back to the first screen, i.e. the list of apps. (continued below)

Comment: So, all was working as required. Then, I wanted to add in a Tab Bar to allow for a front description screen (Home), the apps list (Apps), and a third for info (Info), support, etc.  When I added the Tab Bar controller, everything works OK, except that when one of the apps within the 'Apps' tab is loaded, tapping the button that activates 'goHome' takes me to the first 'Home' screen and not the list of apps, i.e. the 'Apps' tab. Hopefully, that explains the situation a bit better! Any help appreciated as I am really struggling with this.

Comment: ok, thanks. please, explain/show how you go from the app list to the actual app view... are you presenting the "sub app" modally? inside of a navigation controller?

Comment: Thanks again, sergio.  The code is like this for each app (don't know how to format it here in the comment) Volumes is a name. I hope this helps: -(void) gotoVolumes
{
    UIStoryboard *VolumesStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"VolumesStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *Volumesapp = [VolumesStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    Volumesapp.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:Volumesapp animated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: Yes, sergio!  That is the answer. I cannot thank you enough. I've spent 2-3 days trying to get this working.  Well done!